# How to Parse Lines With Differing Number of Fields in C++

Tags: c++, parsing, stringstream

I have a data that looks like this:

```
AAA 0.3 1.00 foo chr1,100
AAC 0.1 2.00 bar chr2,33
AAT 3.3 2.11     chr3,45
AAG 1.3 3.11 qux chr1,88
ACA 2.3 1.33     chr8,13
ACT 2.3 7.00 bux chr5,122
```

Note that the lines above are tab separated. Moreover, 
it sometime may contain 5 fields or 4 fields.

What I want to do is to capture 4th fields in variable as "" if it doesn't contain any value.

I have the following codes, but somehow it reads the 5th fields, as 4th fields
when 4th is empty.

What's the correct way to do it?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

int main  ( int arg_count, char *arg_vec[] ) {
    string line;
    ifstream myfile (arg_vec[1]);

    if (myfile.is_open())
    {
        while (getline(myfile,line) )
        {
            stringstream ss(line);    
            string Tag;  
            double Val1;
            double Val2;
            double Field4;
            double Field5;

            ss >> Tag >> Val1 >> Val2 >> Field4 >> Field5;
            cout << Field4 << endl;
            //cout << Tag << "," << Val1 << "," << Val2 << "," << Field4 << "," << Field5 << endl;

        }
        myfile.close();
    }
    else { cout << "Unable to open file"; }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you say more about your input? Do you have a way of knowing when a line is going to have 4 fields or 5 fields?

Comment: @Tom: At most it can contain 5 fields and first 3 fields always exist.

Comment: It seems odd that Field4 and Field5 are expected to be double given the nature of the data you show!  Since the system doesn't know about your division of the data, you will have to move the data from Field4 to Field5 when Field5 is empty.  The answers are giving automatic was to do that.

Comment: Columns are tab separated, right? What then these ',' are?

Comment: And I suppose the empty value still surrounded with "\t" tab symbol as it usually in the 'something separated file'.

Comment: are the lines or the fields tab separated? lines seem to be separated by newline

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another C++ only version that just uses the fact that istream must set the failbit if operator>> fails to parse.

```
while(getline(ss, line))
{
    stringstream sl(line);

    sl >> tag >> v1 >> v2 >> v3 >> v4;

    if(sl.rdstate() == ios::failbit) // failed to parse 5 arguments?
    {
        sl.clear();
        sl.seekg(ios::beg);
        sl >> tag >> v1 >> v2 >> v4; // do it again with 4
        v3 = "EMPTY"; // just a default value
    }


    cout << "tag: " << tag <<std::endl
        << "v1: " << v1 << std::endl
        << "v2: " << v2 << std::endl
        << "v3: " << v3 << std::endl
        << "v4: " << v4 << std::endl << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: It is hard to change if two of them can be zero.

Comment: @Mykola: Correct, I'm still trying to figure out how to cleanly create some sort of stream manipulator that allows for optional parameters.

Answer (score 6):

Tokenize the line into a vector of strings and then do conversion to an appropriate data type depending on the number of tokens.

If you can use [Boost.Spirit](http://spirit.sourceforge.net/), this reduces to a simple problem of defining an appropriate grammar.

Comment: Why was this downvoted? It's the correct answer, as far as I can see.

Comment: You can use boost::tokenizer for option 1.

Comment: @dribeas: Good point. I specifically wanted to mention Spirit since I haven't seen this one much here on SO :)

Comment: Tokenizer skips empty columns. Do you know how to handle this?

Answer (score 4):

If you want to give Boost.Spirit a try, start with this. It does compile and i have tested it a bit. It seems to work fine.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <list>
#include <boost/spirit/core.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/actor/assign_actor.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace boost::spirit;

struct OneLine
{
        string tag;
        double val1;
        double val2;
        string field4;
        string field5;
};

int main  ( int arg_count, char *arg_vec[] ) {
    string line;
    ifstream myfile (arg_vec[1]);
    list<OneLine> myList;

    if (myfile.is_open())
    {
        while (getline(myfile,line) )
        {
                OneLine result;
                rule<> good_p(alnum_p|punct_p);
                parse( line.c_str(),
                    (*good_p)[assign_a(result.tag)] >> ch_p('\t') >>
                    real_p[assign_a(result.val1)] >> ch_p('\t') >>
                    real_p[assign_a(result.val2)] >> ch_p('\t') >>
                    (*good_p)[assign_a(result.field4)] >> ch_p('\t') >>
                    (*good_p)[assign_a(result.field5)],
                    ch_p(";") );

                myList.push_back( result );
        }
        myfile.close();
    }
    else { cout << "Unable to open file"; }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

With boost:

```
int main()
{
    std::ifstream in("parsefile.in");

    if (!in)
        return 1;

    typedef std::istreambuf_iterator<char> InputIterator;
    typedef boost::char_separator<char> Separator;
    typedef boost::tokenizer< Separator, InputIterator > Tokenizer;

    Tokenizer tokens(InputIterator(in),
                     InputIterator(),
                     Separator(",\t\n", "", boost::keep_empty_tokens));

    const std::size_t columnsCount = 6;
    std::size_t columnNumber = 1;
    for(Tokenizer::iterator it = tokens.begin(); 
        it != tokens.end(); 
        ++it)
    {
        const std::string value = *it;

        if ( 2 == columnNumber )
        {
            const double d = convertToDouble(value);
        }

        std::cout << std::setw(10) << value << "|";

        if ( columnsCount == columnNumber )
        {
            std::cout << std::endl;
            columnNumber = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            ++columnNumber;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Without boost:

```
int main()
{
    std::ifstream in("parsefile.in");

    if (!in)
        return 1;

    const std::size_t columnNumber = 5;
    while (in)
    {
        std::vector< std::string > columns(columnNumber);

        for (std::size_t i = 0; i < columnNumber - 1; ++i)
            std::getline(in, columns[i], '\t');
        std::getline(in, columns[columnNumber - 1], '\n');

        std::cout << columns[3] << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

To convert string value to double you can use the following.

```
double convertToDouble( const std::string& value )
{
    std::stringstream os;
    os << value;
    double result;
    os >> result;
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest thing is just to use two calls to fscanf, scanf or sscanf like so:

```
std::string line = /* some line */;
if(sscanf(line.c_str(), "%s %f %f %s", &str1, &float1, &float2, &str2) == 4){
    // 4 parameters
}else if(sscanf(line.c_str(), ...) == 5){
    // 5 parameters
}
```

Using boost::Spirit seems like overkill, though this isn't the most C++-ish way of doing things.

Comment: The user wants to read into a std::string - you can't do that with scanf()

Comment: You can with sscanf, which takes a const char *

Comment: I said READ INTO, not READ FROM!

Comment: what a mix of C and C++. why not stringstream or something?

Comment: @Neil: Although it's possible to convert the data into std::string after parsing, the OP doesn't mention it.

Comment: yes, he does - "string Tag" is the first thing he wants to read into

Comment: @Neil: You're right, I'm still leaving this answer in because of it's simplicity. Converting to the char* to std::string is trivial.

Answer (score 1):

Yet another version - I think this is the one that involves the least typing!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {

    string f1, f4;
    double f2, f3, f5;

    string line;
    istringstream is;

    while( getline( cin, line ) ) {

        is.str( line );

        if ( ! (is >> f1 >> f2 >> f3 >> f4 >> f5) ) {
            is.str( line);
            f4 = "*";
            is >> f1 >> f2 >> f3 >> f5;
        }

        cout << f1 << " " << f2 << " " << f3 << " " << f4 << " " << f5 << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: operator!() also fails on badbit, which you might not want :-). Other than that, it's pretty similar to my previous solution.

Answer (score 1):

One more generic solution to read and handle any text based table. Solution is with boost.

```
typedef boost::function< void (int, int, const std::string&) > RecordHandler;
void readTableFromFile( const std::string& fileName,
                        const std::string& delimiter,
                        RecordHandler handler );

void handler(int row, int col, const std::string& value)
{
    std::cout << "[ " << row << ", " << col << "] " << value;
}

int main()
{
    readTableFromFile("parsefile.in", "\t,", handler);

    return 0;
}
```

And the Implementation

```
std::size_t columnsCountInTheFile( const std::string& fileName,
                                   const std::string& delimiter )
{
    typedef boost::char_separator<char> Separator;
    typedef boost::tokenizer< Separator > Tokenizer;

    std::ifstream in(fileName.c_str());

    std::string line;
    std::getline(in, line);

    Tokenizer t(line,
                Separator(delimiter.c_str(), "", boost::keep_empty_tokens));

    return std::distance(t.begin(), t.end());
}

void readTableFromFile( const std::string& fileName,
                        const std::string& delimiter,
                        RecordHandler handler );
{
    std::ifstream in(fileName.c_str());

    if (!in)
        throw std::runtime_error("can't read from " + fileName);

    typedef std::istreambuf_iterator<char> InputIterator;
    typedef boost::char_separator<char> Separator;
    typedef boost::tokenizer< Separator, InputIterator > Tokenizer;

    Tokenizer tokens(InputIterator(in),
                     InputIterator(),
                     Separator((delimiter + "\n").c_str(), "", boost::keep_empty_tokens));

    const std::size_t columnsCount = columnsCountInTheFile(fileName, delimiter);

    std::size_t columnNumber = 1;
    std::size_t rowNumber = 1;
    for(Tokenizer::iterator it = tokens.begin(); 
        it != tokens.end(); 
        ++it)
    {
        handler(rowNumber, columnNumber, *it);

        if ( columnsCount == columnNumber )
        {
            columnNumber = 1;
            ++rowNumber;
        }
        else
        {
            ++columnNumber;
        }
    }
}
```